# Why does my home have three empty, inaccessible rooms?

Tags: drywall, walls

I spent the past hour to draw a map of my home, and this is the result:

[image]

As you can see from the plant, there are 3 hollow areas labelled as A, B and C.

- The area A is just behind the kitchen
- The area B is just behind the pipes of the gas counter.
- The area C is between two bathrooms

I tried to give explanations to each of them:

## A

The "room" is made out of drywall and if I knock on it is obviously empty.
There aren't any evident pipes in it, because the water for the kitchen comes from the wall on the left (the cm207.4 wall).
There's just the tube for the extractor hood on the top of it, but I hardly believe a ~1 square meter chamber is needed just for this purpose...

## B

The gas counter is on the right of this room, part of it may be needed for the gas pipes, but again, it's a quite big area just for few pipes?

## C

This is between two bathrooms so I thought it could be needed for the discharge of the waters, but I never seen a so large area dedicated to this, in my previous home there wasn't any relevant space reserved for this stuff.

---

To give some context, this is a Hungarian (Budapest) home, built on top of an existing historic building (they added 2 new floors). I live on the first of the 2 added floors.

This is a picture from Google Maps of my building:
[image]

I would like to, at least, get rid of the area A, because it takes a lot of space. But I'm not sure if this is something feasible or not.

Do you have better explanations for the presence of these areas (especially A)?

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask -- This site isn't suited to this kind of open-ended speculation, it is intended for questions about specific problems you face for which people can provide a definite correct answer. You don't say what sort of problem is caused by the existence of these spaces. An answer is likely to be to go find the plans submitted to the local building authority when the new floors were constructed.

Comment: Hi, I improved the question.

I'm looking for authoritative answers from people with experience in buildings that may find it obvious the purpose of these empty spaces.

Comment: Are there floors above yours?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Nope I just have the area shown by the plant

Comment: Also, are those areas accessible on floors *below* yours?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not sure, being homes of other people I haven't any way to know it.

Comment: @FezVrasta -- they *are* your neighbors, ask them perhaps?

Comment: They all look like standard closets to me. I have no idea why they were left closed.

Comment: They might carry HVAC ducting?  How is air distribution and returns handled in your building?

Comment: @Tyson there isn't any air distribution, the building has a court in the middle  and all the apartments have direct access to it, so there aren't closed spaces apart from the apartment themselves, but they have just windows for air distribution. Something like this: http://www.hotelroomsearch.net/im/hotels/hu/ringavenue-apartments-budapest-1.jpg

Comment: No forced air heating or air conditioning?  I'll admit I don't know much about the climate there, or methods for heating/cooling.  Cooking exhaust?  Does viewing the roof from say Google maps/Google earth give any clues?

Comment: @Tyson I added a picture from Google Maps

Comment: It's likely there to conceal utilities and/or structure. The only ways to know for sure, are to ask the building owner or look inside.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be answered definitively by a group of folks on the internet.

Comment: The only approach here is to ask your building manager. But in the google earth, I see a lot of multiple-vent chimneys (the white things) almost exactly that size.  If "B" was clear, then the 10.10m room would be an utterly incompetent waste of space.  NO designer would do that!  This proves definitively "B" can only be unusable structural space.  Therefore, the others too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the locations and sizes of those areas they are almost certainly pipe chases.  When drawing, framing, and drywalling a residence, it is common for spec builders to simply block out the space around pipes, supports, and ducts – with little effort to optimize the use or availability of such small spaces.

Of course, this means that there is a good chance you could use those spaces.  For example, when I run out of projects I will often cut an inspection panel into the drywall and, based on what I find:

1. Turned them into closets
2. Built-in bookshelves
3. Added discrete hatches for hidden storage

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean there's no chance to completely get rid of the area A? :-(

Comment: @FezVrasta It's possible: It could have been planned as a closet but not drawn correctly so the framers and/or drywallers just covered every side.  The only way to determine whether you can open it up is to first cut an inspection hole in the wall, and then (if it's empty) verify that the framing you want to remove isn't load-bearing.